# Customize layout of Panel and Launcher in Unity

Tags: unity, launcher, panel, customization

Just wondering if there is a way to adjust the Launcher to take 100% of the screen's height and have the Panel at the top fill the width beside it.

Currently it looks like this:

[image]

but I'd prefer it to look like this:

[image]

The change is in the top left corner. It is subtle but really bothers me as the Launcher looks like it is part of the window.